# 502 Error: CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I’m using `CloudFront` to setup a `CDN` for a WordPress installation. It worked for years, but I ran into an issue when I moved the whole site to HTTPS and set it up with a `SSL certificate`. A couple of things:

1. the site itself has a valid certificate, which I checked using a SSL checker;
2. the `CNAME` I’m using for the `CDN` (like `image.website.com`) also has its own `SSL certificate`, which I also checked. Intermediate certificate is also good and valid.
3. Of course the distribution is set to point to the custom `CNAME`, which was validated by `AWS` (using `DNS` protocole)
4. I tried different configuration of the Origin Protocol Policy setting in my distribution, but the problem persists.

Maybe something to do with the header. If anyone could help me troubleshooting this I would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: The distribution shown here seems to be working, now.  Is that what you see?

Answer (score 0):

The distribution is working. It seems that changing the Origin Protocol Policy to “HTTP only” did the trick. After implementing changes in distribution settings, some time is needed for them to fully take effect.